# Sort legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced a stacked percent barplot from the following data, which is in a csv file,

```
,ONE,TWO,THREE
1,2432,420,18
2,276,405,56
3,119,189,110
4,90,163,140
5,206,280,200
6,1389,1080,1075
7,3983,3258,4878
8,7123,15828,28111
9,8608,48721,52576
10,9639,44725,55951
11,8323,45695,32166
12,2496,18254,26600
13,1524,8591,18583
14,7861,1857,1680
15,10269,5165,4618
16,13560,64636,63262
```

using the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

data <- read.csv(file="file.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
data <- data[,2:ncol(data)]
datam <- melt(cbind(data,ind = sort(rownames(data))),is.var = c('ind'))
datam$ind <- as.numeric(datam$ind)
ggplot(datam,aes(x = variable, y = value,fill = factor(as.numeric(ind)))) +
geom_bar(position = "fill") + scale_y_continuous(labels =percent_format()) +
scale_fill_discrete("Barcode\nMatch")  +xlab("Barcode")+ylab("Reads")
```

The result is
[image]

The problem is that the items in the legend are not in the same order as the stacks they represent. The colours and the numbers are right but the order is not. In other words, is there a way to invert the order of the items in the legend? Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can use a new option `reverse = TRUE`:

```
ggplot(datam,aes(x = variable, y = value,fill = factor(as.numeric(ind)))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + scale_y_continuous(labels =percent_format()) +
  scale_fill_discrete("Barcode\nMatch") + xlab("Barcode")+ylab("Reads") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `+ scale_fill_hue(breaks=c("new order 1","new order 2","new order..."))` as in:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, fill=group)) + geom_bar() + 
    geom_bar(colour="black", legend=FALSE) + 
    scale_fill_hue(breaks=c("trt1","ctrl","trt2"))
```

I'd also check out [http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Legends%20(ggplot2)/](http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Legends%20%28ggplot2%29/) for more.

This may have changed and become easier with he new ggplot but I'm not sure.

Comment: Here is an updated link for more Legends info: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/.