# ggplot reorder factors in plot without affecting legend order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to reorder the factors of my plot without affecting the legend order.

For instance:

```r
library(ggplot)
library(data.table)

n <- 1000
X <- data.table(score = c(rnorm(n, -4, 1), rnorm(n, 0, 3)),
                group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = n))

X[, group := factor(group, levels = c("B", "A"))]

ggplot(X, aes(score, fill = group, color = group)) + 
  geom_density(aes(y=..scaled..)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "firebrick4")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "firebrick4"))
```

[image]

As you can see, the legend is also affected by the factor's levels order. This is what I would like to obtain:

[image]

Comment: Add `+ guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE), fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`

Comment: Also note that `scale_*_manual` has an `aesthetics` argument that you might want to set to `c('fill', 'colour')` to save some typing.

Comment: @markus It works, thanks! You may want to submit your answer so I can validate it.

Comment: Glad it worked. Marked your question as a dupe as this answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578264/8583393 covers your problem.